# Dart Sprite in StageXL recognizes MouseEvent, but not TouchEvent

Tags: dart, stagexl

I have a class that extends Sprite, and implements Touchable.

The mouse listener works perfectly, but touch does not.

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _mouseDown);
this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, _touchDown);

Any ideas why this could be happening? I currently just have:

void _touchDown(TouchEvent e) {print("touched");}, and it is not being called. I am using Chromium and emulating touch.

Answer (score 0):

You have top opt-in to get touch event, otherwise you will always get mouse events. Do it this way:

```
if (Multitouch.inputMode.supportsTouchEvents) {
  Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
}
```

Comment: That works. Kind of. I'm currently using a library that deals with multi touch. I can't find any documentation about that for StageXL. There is no .changedTouches for TouchEvent in StageXL. Suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, I see. TouchEvents work exactly the same as MouseEvents. I'm guessing StageXL has a different event system from Dart.